# Yii2: how to redirect old URLs with 301?

Tags: php, yii2, yii-url-manager

I have some URLs from the old version of my site that I want to redirect to their new ones in Yii2 due to SEO purposes, eg. `/about-us.php` to `/about`. How do I do that?

I can't use `.htaccess`, and I can't use `urlManager` rules because HTTP response status 301 needs to be set.

I tried the following in a bootstrap class but even though the code executes I still just get a 404 when going to the old URL:

```php
if (preg_match("|^/about.php|", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    Yii::$app->response->redirect('/about', 301)->send();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `.htaccess` for that, I mean it's not the job of the application to redirect old URLs !

Comment: Why not? Why have Apache read that info from .htaccess on every single request when you can just execute that code conditionally based on a simple variable within PHP? I found the solution now actually...

Comment: You really need to learn more about URL rewriting and what permanent redirect is. Good luck.

Comment: Well inform me then - I'm all ears - what is it I don't understand?

Comment: Please mark my answer as Accepted Answer if the solution helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the answer myself. My bootstrap attempt was not so bad, I just needed to add `Yii::$app->end()`:

```php
if (preg_match("|^/about-us.php|", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    Yii::$app->response->redirect('/about', 301)->send();
    Yii::$app->end();
    return;
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64158405/2404541) is also another variant.

Comment: @sabinonstack You create a class under the `components` folder and put code in there you want to always run. Then you configure Yii to always run this class when initializing the application, like this: https://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/bKKJ/yii2-execute-my-code-before-any-action-of-any-controller - except I make the class implement the BootstrapInterface. Eg.: `class Bootstrap implements BootstrapInterface { public function bootstrap($app) { //your code } }`

Answer (score 4):

there is a cleaner and easier way to do it:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        if (in_array($action->id, ['about-us'])) {
            Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::to(['about']), 301);
            Yii::$app->end();
        }
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
}
```

Hope that will be helpful!

Comment: First, it will only work for that controller - unless I extend all other controllers from this one (which I'd prefer not to do). Secondly, the old URL does not by default resolve to a Yii action due to the `.php` extension.

Answer (score 0):

Yii 1.1

```
public function actionOldPage()
{
    Yii::app()->request->redirect('redirect/to/this', true, 301);
}
```

First I tried UrlManager in config/main.php

'oldPage'=>'newPage'

but it's redirect as 302